# How to create TYPO3 Multiselect with Content type plugin?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I am facing one issue, My requirement is to open one tt_content plugin after clicking the '+' icon in the Back end. [See below]
[[image: Issue1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXaZn.png)

Like we have here in plugin wizards
[image]

Comment: You *might* be able to do that by substituting the FieldControl/AddRecord with an own element for this case. See more details about node expansion at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html#node-expansion

Comment: You *might* be able to do that with an own FieldControl/AddRecord. See more details about node expansion at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html#node-expansion

A kickstart video about that new core v8 functionality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=up00wzDz7vI

You probably need to route to an own "AddController" (wizard_add route) in your "AddRecord" FieldControl, then feed FormEngine with "defVals" (that's how EditDocumentController hands default values from content element wizard).

So, not trivial, but probably doable.

Comment: Thanks for reply and I am going to Look into this but my TYPO3 version is 7.6x , is it possible to do that?

Comment: No idea on v7, this area has been rewritten in v8 to allow custom stuff like that. You will at least have a much harder time on v7 to achieve that and your code wouldn't survive a v8 upgrade since you probably need to hack / substitute the one or the other core class. Read: not recommended to do that with v7, and doable but not trivial with v8.